# Creating a JSON object from a List of Lists

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var data = [
    [
        "default_PROJECT",
        "Allow",
        "Connect",
        "Allow",
        "AddComment",
        "Allow",
        "Write",
        "Allow",
        "ViewComments",
        "Allow",
        "ExportData",
        "Allow",
        "ExportImage",
        "Allow",
        "ViewUnderlyingData",
        "Allow",
        "Read",
        "Allow",
        "ShareView",
        "Allow",
        "Filter"
    ],
    [
        "Allow",
        "ExportImage",
        "Allow",
        "Write",
        "Allow",
        "ViewComments",
        "Allow",
        "ShareView",
        "Allow",
        "Filter",
        "Allow",
        "ExportData",
        "Allow",
        "Connect",
        "Allow",
        "Read",
        "Allow",
        "ViewUnderlyingData",
        "Allow",
        "AddComment",
        "Allow",
        "ViewComments",
        "Deny",
        "ExportData",
        "Allow",
        "AddComment",
        "Deny",
        "Write",
        "Allow",
        "Read",
        "Deny",
        "ExportXml",
        "Deny",
        "ShareView",
        "Allow",
        "Connect",
        "Allow",
        "ChangeHierarchy",
        "Allow",
        "WebAuthoring",
        "Deny",
        "ViewUnderlyingData",
        "Deny",
        "Filter",
        "Deny",
        "ExportImage"
    ]
];


var newObj = {};

for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  //newObj['name'] = data[i][0];
  for(j=1; j<data[i].length;j++){
   newObj[data[i][j+1]] = data[i][j];
   document.write(data[i][j] + "----");
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

I am trying to make an array of objects where each object has the "Name" which is the first element of the array, and then the value associated with the value either "ALLOW" or "Deny".  For example I would like to get:

```
{name: "default_PROJECT", connect: "Allow", AddComment: "Allow"} ... etc
```

However some of the arrays have have duplicate keys and if that value is Deny it will always trump a previous value of Deny.

I started with iterating over each array and then trying to push following element has the key?  Am I on the write track?

Comment: Why is the data set up like this in the first place? Does it need to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data  =[["default_PROJECT","Allow","Connect","Allow","AddComment","Allow","Write",
"Allow","ViewComments","Allow","ExportData","Allow","ExportImage","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","Read","Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter"],
["Allow","ExportImage","Allow","Write","Allow","ViewComments",
"Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter","Allow","ExportData","Allow","Connect","Allow",
"Read","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","AddComment","Allow","ViewComments","Deny","ExportData","Allow",
"AddComment","Deny","Write","Allow","Read","Deny","ExportXml","Deny","ShareView","Allow","Connect","Allow","ChangeHierarchy","Allow",
"WebAuthoring","Deny","ViewUnderlyingData","Deny","Filter","Deny","ExportImage"]];


var result = [];

for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
  var list = data[i];
  
  result[i] = { name: list[0] };

  for(var j = list.length - 1; j >= 1; j = j - 2) {
    var key = list[j];
    var value = list[j - 1];
    
    console.log('calc', j, key, value);
    

    result[i][key] = value;

    
  }
}

/** IGNORE THIS, IS JUST FOR DEBBUGGING **/
var resultElement = document.getElementById('result1');
var tpl = '';
for(var t = 0, tLen = result.length; t < tLen; t++) {
  var item = result[t];
  
  tpl+= '<table>' +
    '<thead>' +
      '<tr><td colspan="2">' + item.name + '</td></tr>' +
      '<tr><th>KEY</th><th>VAL</th></tr>' +
      '</thead>' +
    '<tbody>'
  ;
  
  for(var key in item) {
    if(!item.hasOwnProperty(key) || key === 'name') { continue; }
    
    tpl += '<tr><td>'+ key +'</td><td>'+ item[key] +'</td></tr>';   
  }
      
  
  tpl += '</tbody></table>';
}
resultElement.innerHTML = tpl;
```

```css
table { text-align: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px; border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th { width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; line-height: 1; padding:2px 10px;}
[colspan="2"] { color: blue; font-weight: bolder;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
```

---

Comment: using the top one I get a result like: [{"name":"default_PROJECT","Connect":"Allow","AddComment":"Allow","Write":"Allow","ViewComments":"Allow","ExportData":"Allow","ExportImage":"Allow","ViewUnderlyingData":"Allow","Read":"Allow","ShareView":"Allow","Filter":""},{"name":"testing_PROJECT","ExportImage":"","Write":"Allow","ViewComments".....  For some reason it is cutting off the last value and the first value of each object?

Comment: The value is before the key, besides the first element of the array.

Comment: This is the worst data structure I ever seen, you should consider a **little** refactoring!